# Looking to adapt Mitutoyo 26mm x 36tpi (0.706") to 77mm filter thread

Tags: lens, adapter, microscopy

This is to mount a Mitutoyo objective to the front of my typical lenses which have 77mm filter thread.  Ideally the objective would be as close to the front of the lens it's fitted to as possible, so it's better to use as few step up rings as possible.

I haven't seen any, but I already have adapters for M42 to 77mm, so a BD 26 to M42, 52mm or especially to 77mm would be great.  Has anyone solved this issue or seen one of these adapters for sale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? This [M26x0.7 (36 tpi, Mitutoyo) female to M77x0.75 male thread adapter](http://www.rafcamera.com/en/adapters/adapters-for-filter-thread/m77x0-75/adapter-m26x0-7-to-m77x0-75) at rafcamera.com goes straight from the Mitutoyo mount to 77mm filter size, skipping the M42 mount.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that one.  It does adapt directly between my target thread sizes.  It's also about five times as expensive as the typical adapters, but perhaps that's based on the small supply.  I will have to try this when my budget improves!

Comment: @OldUncleHo Also, it's located in Russia, so perhaps the shipping cost is a factor in the price. Their stuff is sold on eBay for a couple bucks more than the price listed at their website, but their listings say shipping is free. Just be prepared to wait several weeks for delivery.